# CSS no navbar transparency in ul section

Tags: css

I have a problem with my navbar. It looks like this:
[image: Navbar]

It's allo good, but i want that the transparency is the same all over the whole navbar. Now it looks like that only the parts without the links is transparent.

Here is my code. 
HTML:

```css
     
    .nav-collapse {
      height: 35px;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
      background-color: rgba(38, 44, 58, 0.8);
      color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
      *zoom: 1;
    }
    .nav-collapse ul {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 400px;
      height: 35px;
    }
    .nav-collapse li {
      float: left;
      display: inline;
    }
    .nav-collapse a {
      font-family: "lavanderia_regular", Georgia, serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100px;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #a7dbdb;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 35px;
    }
    .nav-collapse a:hover {
      color: #69d2e7;
    }
    .nav-collapse:before, .nav-collapse:after {
      content: " ";
      display: table;
    }
    .nav-collapse:after {
      clear: both;
    }
    
    #pull {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
   <nav class="nav-collapse">
   <ul class="nav-collapse">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bilder</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Rezepte</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
   </ul>
   <a href"#" id="pull">Menu</a>
  </nav>
```

Comment: set the link's background color to transparent? As it seems like the two partial opacities are muliplying?

Comment: The `nav` and the `ul` both have the class `nav-collapse`, so both get the background of `rgba(38, 44, 58, 0.8)`, but for the `ul`, the opacity gets rendered against its background (the `nav`). You should only apply that to the `nav`, not the `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `background-color: transparent;` to the CSS class `.nav-collapse ul`. Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ytyoy6zv/

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go. But you probably want to use different class names for these different elements.

```css
.nav-collapse {
      height: 35px;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
      background-color: rgba(38, 44, 58, 0.8);
      color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
      *zoom: 1;
    }
    .nav-collapse ul {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 400px;
      height: 35px;
      box-shadow:none; /* since you're reusing the nav-collapse class... override */
      background-color:transparent; /* and override background-color too */
    }
    .nav-collapse li {
      float: left;
      display: inline;
    }
    .nav-collapse a {
      font-family: "lavanderia_regular", Georgia, serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100px;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #a7dbdb;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 35px;
    }
    .nav-collapse a:hover {
      color: #69d2e7;
    }
    .nav-collapse:before, .nav-collapse:after {
      content: " ";
      display: table;
    }
    .nav-collapse:after {
      clear: both;
    }
    
    #pull {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<nav class="nav-collapse">
    <ul class="nav-collapse">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bilder</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Rezepte</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href"#" id="pull">Menu</a>
</nav>
```